# Swift json delete key

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to parsing my json file without "results" tab my new json file

```
[
  {
    "Id": 708,
    "Name": "My name",
    "ImageUrl": "2016728135316.jpg"
  }
```

Codes under below

```
   private func getMoviesFromJSON(jsonData: NSData) throws -> [Movie] {
        var movies = [Movie]()
        do {
            if let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject], jsonArray = jsonObject["results"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for i in jsonArray {
                    var properties = [String: AnyObject]()
                    properties[JSONKeys.id] = i[JSONKeys.id]
                    properties[JSONKeys.title] = i[JSONKeys.title]
                    properties[JSONKeys.posterPath] = i[JSONKeys.posterPath]
                    let movie = Movie(properties: properties)
                    movies.append(movie)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
        }
        return movies
    }
```

I think must be change this line or must be delete.

> jsonObject["results"]

I need your help , Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json doesn't have any `results` parameter .. so you don't need it at all ..

```
     do {
        if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for i in jsonArray {
                var properties = [String: AnyObject]()
                properties[JSONKeys.id] = i[JSONKeys.id]
                properties[JSONKeys.title] = i[JSONKeys.title]
                properties[JSONKeys.posterPath] = i[JSONKeys.posterPath]
                let movie = Movie(properties: properties)
                movies.append(movie)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
    }
```

Comment: @El Captain V2.0 Thank you worked I will aprove your answer.